# Drag & drop from outside the browser

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I didn't find a documentation of how to handle dropping of URLs or media files from outside into a Primefaces web app (browser). There are four examples at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd but they only handle drag & drop inside the web app.

Comment: Use the fileupload  component for this

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, there is dragDropSupport="true" for p:fileUpload. May be, there could be a cross link from DragDrop on the demo site

Comment: dragDropSupport only enables the possibility, to drag a file into the droppable area but a URL can't be dropped. Is there a way to handle a URL-drop from the browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124320/drag-and-drop-a-url-into-a-browser-and-process-using-jquery I think a url is just treated as text. Since html5 does the same https://html5demos.com/drag-anything/